# MVC/Razor model binding collections when an element is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, collections, model-binding

I've got a form that contains a variable length list of textboxes, rendered using a template similar to this..

```
 @Html.TextBox("items[" + itemIndex + "].Title", someValue)
```

So the final rendered HTML looks something like this...

```
<input id="items_0__Amount" type="text" value="Apple" name="items[0].Title">
<input id="items_1__Amount" type="text" value="Banana" name="items[1].Title">
<input id="items_2__Amount" type="text" value="Orange" name="items[2].Title">
```

On form submission this binds to my model just fine. However, I have a delete button that uses Javascript to remove one or more rows from the form. The problem is that, if you delete say the middle row, the HTML looks like this...

```
<input id="items_0__Amount" type="text" value="Apple" name="items[0].Title">
<input id="items_2__Amount" type="text" value="Orange" name="items[2].Title">
```

...and the indexes are no longer contiguous. This seems to confuse MVC and my model binder only gets passed the first row, not the last. Have I done something wrong, or does MVC just fail if indexes in lists aren't contiguous? What is the best solution to this problem?

I want to avoid using JS to re-index everything if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Phil Haack blogged about something similar to this a while ago, although I'm not sure if it is still relevant to MVC 3. The post includes a work-around for the non-sequential index problem -

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx