# MVC 5 / Razor working with the index

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-5

I can output a list, and I can add and remove items from the list, client side with javascript and partial views. But the resulting non-sequential indices cause a problem when the form is submitted.

For example, this code from the first link below

```
<input id="items_0__Amount" type="text" value="Apple" name="items[0].Title">
<input id="items_1__Amount" type="text" value="Banana" name="items[1].Title">
<input id="items_2__Amount" type="text" value="Orange" name="items[2].Title">
```

looks like this if I delete a row

```
<input id="items_0__Amount" type="text" value="Apple" name="items[0].Title">
<input id="items_2__Amount" type="text" value="Orange" name="items[2].Title">
```

or like this if I use js to add a new row with a partial view

```
<input id="items_0__Amount" type="text" value="Apple" name="items[0].Title">
<input id="items_1__Amount" type="text" value="Banana" name="items[1].Title">
<input id="items_2__Amount" type="text" value="Orange" name="items[2].Title">
<input id="items_0__Amount" type="text" value="Apple" name="items[0].Title">
```

Here are links to a previous question and a Haacked blog post that address the issue, but don't solve my problems completely.

[MVC/Razor model binding collections when an element is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399454/mvc-razor-model-binding-collections-when-an-element-is-missing)

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

In addition, this content is from the MVC 2 era.

1. Are there other ways to work with lists where the index can be managed?
2. Are there better ways to work with the index for Razor views / partial views in the latest versions of MVC?

Comment: What i would do is add for each input a hidden checkbox field, if the item gets deleted then check the checkbox and hide the element. When it's posted then you can see which items are deleted.

Comment: I like that idea. I still need help outputting items with an index that I determine myself. The best idea I've come up with so far is to loop through the list of items in the editor template and NOT output the ones up through a given index.